# How to curry functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying

I have a function multThree for multiplying 3 numbers which works with currying. However, when I tried extending this to multiplying four numbers using the same structure it doesn't work. Why is this and how could it be fixed?

```
multThree :: Num a => a -> (a -> (a -> a))
multThree x = (*) . (*) x

multFour :: Num a => a -> (a -> (a -> (a -> a)))
multFour x = (*) . (*) . (*) x
```

Error given:

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ a -> a
  Expected type: a -> a -> a -> a
    Actual type: a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
• In the expression: (*) . (*) . (*) x
  In an equation for ‘multFour’: multFour x = (*) . (*) . (*) x
• Relevant bindings include
    x :: a (bound at test2.hs:19:10)
    multFour :: a -> a -> a -> a -> a
```

Comment: This isn't about currying (`multThree` is *already* curried, as its type is `a -> a -> a -> a`, not `(a, a, a) -> a`); it's about composing higher-order functions.

Comment: The hideous point-free form of `multThree` would be `multThree = ((*) .) . (*)`, which (to be honest), is barely worth understanding instead of simply writing the non-point-free version. (`multFour = ((((*) .) . (*)) .) . (*)` is even worse.)

Comment: If you really want a point-free version, you could use `multThree = fmap (*) . (*)` and `multFour = fmap (fmap (*)) . fmap (*) . (*)` = `fmap (fmap (*) . (*)) . (*)` = `fmap multThree . (*)`. The `fmap` is the same as `(.)` but in my opinion makes it a little clearer where you’re “skipping over” arguments. Another way to build a point-free solution is e.g. `multThree = curry ((*) . uncurry (*))`: you’re pairing up two arguments in a tuple, multiplying them together, then multiplying the result by the other argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s write it out without `(.)`:

```
multFour x = (*) . (*) . (*) x
= (*) . (\y -> (y*)) . (x*)
= (\w -> (w*)) . (\z -> ((x*z)*))
= (\w -> (w*)) . (\z v -> x*z*v)
= \z -> \u -> (\v -> x*z*v) * u
```

And so we see that we are trying to multiply a function by a number.

The key error is this:

```
multFour x = (*) . multThree x
```

And the types are:

```
(*) :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)
multThree x :: Num b => b -> (b -> b)
x :: b
(.) :: (y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> (x -> z)
```

So the types unify as:

```
a = y
z = (a -> a)
b = x
y = b -> b
multFour :: Num b => b -> x -> z
multFour :: (Num b, Num (b -> b)) => b -> b -> (b -> b) -> (b -> b)
```

Which is not the type you want it to be.

To fix your code, I recommend:

```
multFour a b c d = a * b * c * d
```

This is much more readable.